# Prove that a covariant functor which satisfies 2 conditions is a cosheaf

Tags: algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Suppose that $\mathfrak{U}$ is a covariant functor on the open sets of $X$ to $\mathbb{Z}$-modules with satisfies the following two conditions :

(a) If $U$ and $V$ are open then the sequence $$\mathfrak{U}(U\cap V)\stackrel{\alpha}{\rightarrow}\mathfrak{U}(U)\oplus\mathfrak{U}(V)\stackrel{\beta}{\rightarrow}\mathfrak{U}(U\cup V)\rightarrow 0$$ is exact, where $\alpha=i_{U,U\cap V}-i_{V,U\cap V}$ and $\beta=i_{U\cup V,U}+i_{U\cup V,V}$.

(b) If $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ is an upward-directed family of open sets with $U=\bigcup U_{\alpha}$, then $\mathfrak{U}(U)=\varinjlim \mathfrak{U}(U_{\alpha})$

How to show that $\mathfrak{U}$ is a cosheaf ?

(Exercise 3 in BREDON G. E., $\textit{Sheaf Theory}$, McGraw-Hill Book Company, New York-Toronto, Ont.-London, 1967, p. 248)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full proof is given by Bredon in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102986387) page 3.

The general idea is that your assuption (a) will give you the cosheaf property for finite coverings. (You can proceed by induction, the case $n=2$ being your assumption.) Then, thanks to an inductive limit and assumption (b) you can get the cosheaf property for any covering.